# Adding constraint to LP model - minimum shifts required - R

Tags: r, capacity-planning

I am working on a problem I have design shifts. The approach I am  taking is

1. shift start and end time - is already defined. (I have 10 shifts at duration of 7 hours that are overlappiing)
2. I using lpsolver in R to compute the FTE numbers.

Out of the 10 shifts that has been defined I want the algorithm to give me FTE only for 4 shifts, meaning, i want to add a constraint as no. of shifts is 4. There is no constraint which shift is being selected

My current code is as follows

```
o=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
C=rbind(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
        c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
        c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1),
        c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1),
        c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1),
        c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1),
        c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1),
        c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1),
        c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1),
        c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1),
        c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
        c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
        c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
        c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
        c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
        c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0),
        c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0),
        c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
        c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
        c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
        c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
        c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
        c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
        c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1)


)

 d=rep(">=",24)


r=c(58,60,62,65,72,80,87,93,93,92,90,86,80,74,68,64,61,60,60,58,55,53,52,55)


sol=lpSolve::lp("min",o,C,d,r,compute.sens = TRUE)
sol$solution
```

Can please let me know how to add a constraint on number of shifts to be considered

Thanks

Comment: what is `o` in your code?

Comment: My code contains 7 shifts , C is the matrix is that shows the 7 shifts where the hour of the day appears. hence it has 24 rows. r is number of FTE required at each hour of the day. The matix is the dummy variables that is constructed

Comment: I have updated the code to show 'o'

Comment: still not clear to me what you are trying to solve because your number of variables is 7 instead 10.